# question on gridfs

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

As one can see in [GridFS doc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS), BSON objects are limited in size. So if I want to store something extremely big, I need to separate it on chunks. It'll be a document in fs.files collection. My question is: is there a way to have huge fields in document. so that it can be found without looking in fs.files collection.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. BSON documents have a hard 16mb limit so individual fields can never exceed this size limitation. It is exactly that limitation GridFS is working around by transparently chunking a larger file amongst multiple smaller segments.